# How to split the grid to two part

Tags: java, swt

I build application with table viewer.

I want to split the screen to two parts : table , message.

The messages should be SWT controller with scroll ( could be alot of messages )

it should look like this

```
       --------------------------------
       -         toolbar of the table -
       --------------------------------
       -                              -
       -        Table                 -
       -                              -
       --------------------------------
       -        message               -
       --------------------------------
```

What is the best SWT control to use for the messages? ( I need control for message + scroll er  )

How I can split the screen ? Do I need to use SashForm ?

```
    GridLayout dsGridLayout = new GridLayout();
    dsGridLayout .numColumns = 1;
    // set layout
    parent.setLayout(dsGridLayout);
    // toolBar 
    GridData tBGridData = new GridData();
    tB.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
    tB.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    // details control grid data
    GridData dGridData = new GridData();
    dGridData.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
    dGridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    dGridData.verticalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
    dGridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
    // Details toolBar
    ToolBar toolBar = createToolBarPart(parent); // Create toolBar for the table
    toolBar.setLayoutData(tBarGridData);
    // Separator line
    createSeperatorLabel(parent);
    // Details control
    Table table = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER ) // Create the table viewer
    table.setLayoutData(dGridData);
```

Comment: Why not use a `GridData.widthHint` for the message part and make the table part grab the remaining space?

Comment: Could you please show me an example for this  ?

Comment: what should be the SWT controller for the messages  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take this code as a starting point:

```
private static Shell    shell;

public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    createToolbar();
    createTablePart();
    createMessagesPart();

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    shell.setSize(500, 350);
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static void createToolbar()
{
    ToolBar toolbar = new ToolBar(shell, SWT.FLAT | SWT.BORDER | SWT.HORIZONTAL | SWT.RIGHT);
    toolbar.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING, true, false));

    String[] labels = new String[] { "A", "B", "C" };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        ToolItem item = new ToolItem(toolbar, SWT.PUSH);
        item.setText(labels[i]);
    }
    toolbar.pack();
}

private static void createTablePart()
{
    Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
    {
        TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
        column.setText("Col " + col);
    }

    for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
    {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        item.setText(0, row + " " + 0);
        item.setText(1, row + " " + 1);
        item.setText(2, row + " " + 2);
    }

    for(TableColumn col : table.getColumns())
        col.pack();
}

private static void createMessagesPart()
{
    Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.WRAP);
    GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.END, true, false);
    data.heightHint = 50;
    text.setLayoutData(data);

    text.setText("First Message\nSecond Message\nThirdMessage\nFourth Message");
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can use a `SashForm` to be able to resize the bottom part:

private static Shell    shell;

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    createToolbar();

    SashForm form = new SashForm(shell, SWT.VERTICAL);
    form.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    createTablePart(form);
    createMessagesPart(form);
    form.setWeights(new int[] { 3, 1 });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    shell.setSize(500, 350);
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static void createToolbar()
{
    ToolBar toolbar = new ToolBar(shell, SWT.FLAT | SWT.BORDER | SWT.HORIZONTAL | SWT.RIGHT);
    toolbar.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING, true, false));

    String[] labels = new String[] { "A", "B", "C" };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        ToolItem item = new ToolItem(toolbar, SWT.PUSH);
        item.setText(labels[i]);
    }
    toolbar.pack();
}

private static void createTablePart(SashForm parent)
{
    Table table = new Table(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
    {
        TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
        column.setText("Col " + col);
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
    {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        item.setText(0, row + " " + 0);
        item.setText(1, row + " " + 1);
        item.setText(2, row + " " + 2);
    }

    for (TableColumn col : table.getColumns())
        col.pack();
}

private static void createMessagesPart(SashForm parent)
{
    Text text = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.WRAP);
    GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.END, true, false);
    data.heightHint = 50;
    text.setLayoutData(data);

    text.setText("First Message\nSecond Message\nThirdMessage\nFourth Message");
}
```

Comment: Could you give me an example how to do it with sashForm ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create eclipse view and add table viewer inside the view.View toolbar can be used as table toolbar,also you can make view non-closable. For messages I suggest to use StyledText control so that you can apply styles(fonts size,font color,font style etc) to messages.